# How to compute first order derivative with DFT?

Tags: python, fft, dft

I'm trying to find a spectral approximation of the derivative of `e^sin(x)` by computing `P'(x)` which is obtained by FFT in my code.

[image]

```
def solve4(N):
xlist = []              #list of all x values
flist = []              #list of all f values
deriv = []              #list of first derivative of all values in f
for j in range(0,N):
    xlist.append((j*2*pi)/N)
for x in xlist:
    flist.append(e**(sin(x)))
for i in range(0,N):
    deriv.append((cos(xlist[i]))*(flist[i]))
P  = np.fft.fft(xlist,N)            #P is an array after xlist's FFT
```

Comment: Hint: the derivative is obtained by multiplying in the Frequency domain by jω.

Comment: Another hint: with Numpy you can simply do `x = np.arange(0,N)*2*pi/N`, and `f = np.exp(np.sin(x))`, etc. It'll be easier if you skip the loops!

Comment: Can you be more specific about frequency